# How can I check the unique username when registering a user?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When registering itself, Firebase checks for the same mail, but I want to make a script check for a unique username. How can I do it?

```
Button(action: {
    if username == username {
        ProgressHUD.showFailed("This username already exists")
    } else {
        guard let image = selectedUIImage else { return }
        viewModel.registerUser(email: email,
                           password: password,
                           username: username,
                           fullname: fullname,
                           profileImage: image)
    }
}, label: {
    if checked == true && email != "" && username != "" && fullname != "" && password != "" && image != nil {
            Text("Sign Up")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                .background(Color.white)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .padding()
    } else{
        
    }
```

Asked in the chat room, I was told to go to the collection and there to check, but I could not write it in code

Comment: Search online for tutorials and look at the documentation. You have to create all the logic yourself. Break the process down into pieces

Comment: Nothing is built into Firebase Authentication to ensure a unique user name. But you can build it on top of Firebase with an online database. That topic has been covered regularly before, so I recommend checking out some of the answers to [relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bswift%5D+unique+username) or other [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+unique+username) on the topic.

Comment: you can do it by creating a collection named username in firebase and check before register a user that collection contains that user name